# Need help solving some boot time errors

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, boot-repair, error-handling

So , I am kind of a newbie I was using Ubuntu 22.04+windows(dual-boot) for few months and deleted the partition via windows disk management and installed Ubuntu 23.04+windows and I am seing these boot errors :

[0 397360] pci 0000:00:07 0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
/dev/nvme0n1p8: clean, 474261/ 13132800 files, 13109990/52428800 blocks
[ 2 539160] Dev 1oopo: unable to read RDB block 8
[3. 025051] dell_smm_humon: unable to get SMM Dell signature

As I went through few forum posts I was able to solve dell_smm_humon error by blacklisting it (didnt understand much about it but worked )

Now currently I have following errors:
**[0 397360] pci 0000:00:07 0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
/dev/nvme0n1p8: clean, 474261/ 13132800 files, 13109990/52428800 blocks
[ 2 539160] Dev 1oopo: unable to read RDB block 8**

and **i was able understand that RDB block 8 error is fine and all and shouldn't be a problem any way to skip them ?? everytime ??and the only problem is that i would save boot time as its taking few more time like seconds.**

Help me solve these errors .(Please mention any code/terminal commands as I am a newbie)

Thank You

Comment: If the system properly boots, you don't need to "solve" anything.

Comment: It boots perfectly fine I just want to save that boot time as mentioned in qn thank you